# Custom Object and Chatter Insert Trigger Creation

Tags: apex, trigger, chatter

I have a trigger on a custom object `trigger cTrigger on C__c(after insert, after update)` that works correctly when a new `C__c` is created. `C__c` also has Chatter posts enabled and I am trying to write a trigger that runs when a new Chatter post is made on any specific `C__c` object. Any help is appreciated. 
I have searched through the documentation and triggers of this type are not mentioned.

Comment: Have you seen documentation on chatter objects [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_fields_not_updated_chatter.htm) & documentation on [feed item](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm)?

Comment: That's helpful but I don't understand how you can use the example to only work on a specific kind of object  if you use:

`trigger FeedItemTrigger on FeedItem (after update) {

    List<FeedAttachment> attachments =  [SELECT Id, Title, Type, FeedEntityId

                                         FROM FeedAttachment

                                         WHERE FeedEntityId IN :Trigger.new ];

    for (FeedAttachment attachment : attachments) {

        System.debug(attachment.Type);

    }
}`

How do only get the posts related `C__c`?

Comment: Please do not post code in comments. Have your original post edited for that purpose. As for your question, I have provided an answer, which will help you to take it from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want to write trigger on Chatter Posts made on specific records, what you want is to write a trigger on *FeedItem* object. You can find more on the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm).

> FeedItem represents an entry in the feed, such as changes in a record feed, including text posts, link posts, and content posts.

The *Record Id* of the `C__c` record where this post is being made will be available in the feed item trigger by accessing the *ParentId* field. You can process anything further related to the original record once you capture the parent id.

Parent Id of the Feed Item is described in the documentation as:

> ID of the object type to which the FeedItem object is related. For example, set this field to a UserId to post to someone’s profile feed, or an AccountId to post to a specific account.

Also refer to the considerations while writing trigger on chatter objects, which can be found at this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_fields_not_updated_chatter.htm).

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I was able to use the documentation to successfully create the trigger on 'FeedItem'! If I may ask, I have a follow-up question: If I wanted to create a trigger for when someone comments on a created 'C__c' Chatter Post would I still need to use 'FeedItem'?

Comment: @Subito - that would be a *[FeedComment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feedcomment.htm)* object